# Concat two SelectNodes htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

My model:

```
public class Event
{
    public string DateOfEvent { get; set; }
    public string Teams { get; set; }
    public string Championship { get; set; }
}
```

DateOfEvent and Teams I parse from table with this code:

```
var matches = currentData.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=' event-header']").
              Select(tr => new Event()
              {
                   DateOfEvent =
                    tr.SelectNodes("./td[1]/table/tr[1]/td[2]//text()[normalize-space()]")
                           .Single()
                           .InnerText.Trim(),
                   Teams = tr.SelectNodes("./td[1]/table/tr[1]/td[3]//text()[normalize-space()]")
                           .Single()
                           .InnerText.Trim(),
               });
```

I have many records with DateOfEvent and Teams. But I need to add to these all records Field Championship, but Its field parse not from table.

```
var b = currentData.DocumentNode.SelectNode("//div[@class ='sport-champ']")
                                .Select(p=> new Event()
                  {
                      Championship = ......
                  });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How you link each Championship data to DateOfEvent and Teams? By position/index or there is a better rule that you can see from the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select a set of `Event`objects with properties `DateOfEvent`, `Teams`, and `Championship`.
`DateOfEvent` and `Teams` come from multiple rows, but there's one `Championship` and it will be the same for each?

In that case, just get `Championship` first:

```
var championship = currentData.DocumentNode.SelectNode("//div[@class ='sport-champ']")
    .InnerText.Trim();
```

and then do your `Select` from the rows:

```
var matches = currentData.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=' event-header']").
    Select(tr => new Event()
    {
        DateOfEvent = tr.SelectNodes("./td[1]/table/tr[1]/td[2]//text()[normalize-space()]")
           .Single()
           .InnerText.Trim(),
       Teams = tr.SelectNodes("./td[1]/table/tr[1]/td[3]//text()[normalize-space()]")
           .Single()
          .InnerText.Trim(),
       Championship = championship
     });
```